# Find the general solutions of the following

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know how to solve the $a_n=A a_{n-1}+B a_{n-2}$ but how can we solve $a_{n+3}=8 a_{n+2}-19a_{n+1}+12a_n$

**Edit:** I cannot find the roots the equation does not  factor

Comment: I assume you mean what @projectilemotion has written in which case it is the exact same idea, use the ansatz $a_n = x^n$ and find $x$ the resulting characteristic equation will be a cubic which involves slightly more algebra.

Comment: Yes probably I cannot understand clealrly but I think yes

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to solve the $a_n=A a_{n-1}+B a_{n-2}$ but how can we solve $a_{n+3}=8 a_{n+2}-19a_{n+1}+12a_n$

As an alternative to the standard approach, the given $3^{rd}$ order homogeneous recurrence can in fact be reduced to a $2^{nd}$ order non-homogeneous one by noticing that:

$$
a_{n+3}=8 a_{n+2}-19a_{n+1}+12a_n \;\;\iff\;\; a_{n+3}-7 a_{n+2} + 12 a_{n+1}= a_{n+2}-7a_{n+1}+12a_n
$$

It follows that $a_{n+2}-7a_{n+1}+12a_n=a_{n+1}-7a_{n}+12a_{n-1}=\cdots=a_2-7a_1+12a_0\,$, which reduces the original problem to the $2^{nd}$ order recurrence:

$$
a_{n+2}=7a_{n+1}-12a_n+C \quad\quad \text{where}\quad C=a_2-7a_1+12a_0
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a [homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). In general, these are given by:
$$a_n=c_1\cdot a_{n-1}+c_2\cdot a_{n-2}+\cdots+ c_k a_{n-k}$$

---

Therefore, you can solve it in a similar way as with the second order recurrence relation $a_n=A\cdot a_{n-1}+B\cdot a_{n-2}$ by using the same ansatz $a_n=r^n$.

Instead of getting the characteristic equation as a quadratic, it will be a cubic equation:
$$r^{n+3}=8r^{n+2}-19r^{n+1}+12r^n \iff r^3-8r^2+19r-12=0$$

Solve the cubic equation. The general solution will be given by: 
$$a_n=c_1\cdot (r_1)^n+c_2\cdot (r_2)^n+c_3\cdot (r_3)^n$$
Where $r_1, r_2$ and $r_3$ are the roots of the cubic. Note that the roots should be distinct for this to be the general solution (The roots are distinct in your case).

Comment: You can be extra fancy and notice that $r = 1$ is a solution and then this problem isn't messy at all!

Comment: @Gregory Indeed, all the roots are integers and distinct in this case!

Comment: @H.ayd **After your edit:** It does factor. Notice that $r=1$ is obviously a solution. Then, by [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), we have:
$$\frac{r^3-8r^2+19r-12}{r-1}=r^2-7r+12$$
Solving the resulting quadratic gives the other two solutions:
$$r^2-7r+12=0$$